# TypeError ".deploy" is not a function hardhat

Tags: javascript, node.js, hardhat

I'm coding an NFT minting page named astro-mint.
And i'm at this point where I have to deploy my contract through hardhat.

But when i run this command

```
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network dexitTestnet
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: AstroMint.deploy is not a function
    at main (/home/astrodude/dxt/astro-mint/scripts/deploy.js:16:39)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/astrodude/dxt/astro-mint/scripts/deploy.js:25:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

This is how my deploy.js looks like

```
const hardhat = require("hardhat");
const { MerkleTree } = require('merkletreejs');
const keccak256 = require('keccak256');
const whiteList = require('../utils/whitelist');

const BASE_URI = 'ipfs://Qmb5A1fFECM2iFHgUioii2khT814nCi6VU9aHXHHqNxHCK/';
const proxyRegistryAddress = '0xf57b2c51ded3a29e6891aba85459d600256cf317';


async function main() {
    const leadNodes = whiteList.map(address => keccak256(address));
    const merkleTree = new MerkleTree(leadNodes, keccak256, { sortPairs : true });
    const root = merkleTree.getRoot();
    
    const AstroMint = hardhat.ethers.getContractFactory('AstroMint');
    const astroMint = await AstroMint.deploy(BASE_URI, root, proxyRegistryAddress);

    await astroMint.deployed();
    console.log('Astro mint is deployed to ', astroMint.address);

}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

and this is how my package.json looks like

```
{
  "name": "astro-mint",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/font": "13.1.2",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers": "^1.0.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers": "^1.0.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^2.0.1",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.0.0",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.0.0",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.3",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.8.1",
    "@typechain/ethers-v5": "^10.1.0",
    "@typechain/hardhat": "^6.1.2",
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.0",
    "@types/mocha": ">=9.1.0",
    "bnc-onboard": "^1.39.1",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "ethers": "^5.7.2",
    "hardhat" : "2.12.6",
    "hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.8",
    "keccak256": "^1.0.6",
    "merkletreejs": "^0.3.9",
    "next": "13.1.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "solidity-coverage": "^0.8.1",
    "ts-node": ">=8.0.0",
    "typechain": "^8.1.0",
    "typescript": ">=4.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
  }
}
```

I have been trying to search the internet but didt not get an answer for this issue.

I have tried to install hardhat numerous times but didt not help

Comment: Print the value of `AstroMint` so we can see if something is assigned incorrectly, that will help me debug what's going on.

Comment: im getting this 

Promise { <pending> }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you need to have `await` before you assign the value of the contract, your promise is currently still pending which is why you get the error message.

Example:

```js
const AstroMint = await hardhat.ethers.getContractFactory('AstroMint');
```

The documentation on this can be found in the Hardhat [quick start guide](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/getting-started#quick-start).

Answer (score 5):

i had the same issue , to mitigate this i found that .deployed() is not available when we want to deploy our contract instead we can use `.waitForDeployment()` but to similarly some of the other main functions such as contract deployed address we used to call `.address()` is also not availble instead we can use .target() to access deployed contract address.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
contractFlashRaw = await ethers.deployContract("your contract name",signer=deployer);

await contractFlashRaw.waitForDeployment();

console.log(contractFlashRaw.target);
```